Probability of nobody envying me, i.e. probability of one of the seven deadly sins
We are 10 people $d_1, \ldots, d_{10}$. Each of us has a complete rank over 10 houses $h_1, \ldots, h_{10}$, meaning I have a top choice, a second top choice, and so on, and I am not indifferent among houses, i.e. I either prefer $h_j$ over $h_i$ or vice versa.
It so happens that houses are assigned to people and we all got a different house. Moreover, each of us is assigned to a house that we rank as third-best.
Suppose that people' preferences over houses are random and uncorrelated across people (i.e. the preferences over houses are a random permutation of [1:10] restricted to each of us having a different third choice). What is the probability that no person envies me? And how many people are not envied by anyone in expectation? And how does this generalize if instead of 10 people and houses, this number is arbitrary, say $n$; and instead of being ranked to our 3rd best house we are assigned to our $k$-best?
Partial answer: my thinking (probably wrong) is as follows. The probability that I, person $d_1$, am envied by person $d_2$ is the probability that, in his random preference list, the house that I got (say $h_1$) appears in position 1 or 2 (it cannot be three, because he is getting his third best choice). The list of preferences includes 10 positions (all possible houses) and one is taken (the third position) so the probability that $d_1$ isn't envied by $d_2$ should be $\frac {7}{9}$?
And this means that the probability that $d_1$ is not envied by any other person from 2-10 is $\left(\frac{7}{9} \right)^9$?.
And this means that there are, on average, $10 \times \left(\frac{7}{9}\right)^9$ people who aren't envied, I guess. But this number is     1.0416 and simulations suggest it should be roughly equal to 3, so I wonder what I did wrong.
I suppose that what I am doing wrong is that the probability that $d_1$ is not envied is not independent from $i_2$ being not envied and so on.
New approach Perhaps it is easier to compute the probability that exactly 2 people are envied, then the probability of exactly 3 people being envied, and so on?

What do you mean by envying a dude? As you only got your third choice, there are two dudes who got the two houses you would have preferred to the one you actually got.

You are absolutely right, I meant dudes who nobody envies. I made edits now. So sorry for this.
